# How to check a "sync" value in an async function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to make some changes on a Chrome extension. I need the extension checks the value and if it is true, then execute a script. If false, then do nothing. I wrote something like this:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(localStorage["statusOfSomething"]){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "file.js" ,runAt:'document_end'});
    }
});
```

But this takes the initial value of `localStorage["statusOfSomething"]` always. So there is an async function to register a listener for "onUpdated". But I need to check the `localStorage["statusOfSomething"]` value of "now", not the value of the time by registering the listener.

How can I do this?

Edit: 
Actually I was trying to check two things:

1. if the website is in the site list of extension
2. if this website is enabled for the extension

Now here the full story;

There are some websites, I defined them on `background.js` file. Let's say;
a.com, b.com ... etc.

```
var sites = [{
    name     : "a",
    wildcard : ["*://a.com/*"],
    js       : "a.js"
},{
    name     : "b",
    wildcard : ["*://b.com/*"],
    js       : "b.js"
}]
```

and there are statuses of the sites (enable/ disable; true/false)
I think it was good to store statuses by localStorage, so I write as initial value `true`:

```
for(var i = 0; i<sites.length; i++){
    localStorage[sites[i].name] =true;
}
```

As option; it was needed to addListener for changes:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "setSite"){
        var name = request.site;
        var status = request.active;

        localStorage[name] = status;
    }
    return true;
});
```

If user checks the checkbox for status option of the website, then `options.js` sends message:

```
$('#' + name).change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(':checked');
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({method: "setSite", site: this.id, active: status}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
});
```

Now, back to `background.js` , for every update of the tab, I need to check these two things together:
1. am I interested in this website?
2. is it enable for me now?

So I wrote:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        var url = tab.url;
        for(var i = 0; i<sites.length; i++){
            var site = sites[i];
            var name = site.name;
            var wildcard = site.wildcard;
            if(localStorage[name] && testUrl(url,wildcard)){
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: site['js'] ,runAt:'document_end'});
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here, I get the value of localStorage[sitename] true

If you are more interested, you can see the code on [github](https://github.com/lacivert/Chrome-Last.fm-Scrobbler/tree/dev) ([the version](https://github.com/lacivert/Chrome-Last.fm-Scrobbler/commit/b983ba8e72e819c1f113f460170475faa2a6f7e3))

Comment: I am confused. The code you have already checks the value of `statusOfSomething` at the time a tab is updated, not when it is registered.

Comment: Well, are you sure? I was thinking this was the problem but by the negative vote and then your comment made me confused as well. I probably miss something else. I will check if another part changes status before this `if` works.

Comment: I am certain. Nothing in the handler is touched until the event is fired. Perhaps if you post more of your code we can help you find the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I added the details and the full code repository link.